# syntax error, unexpected '<' (View:

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Necesito realizar una condición con un dato que pasa de mi controlador a mi vista blade

```
tengo el siguiente query:
$cuota = DB::select('select count(*)+1 cuota from credito where id_cliente='.$id.' and id>(select max(id) id from (SELECT * FROM credito where cantidad>0 and id_cliente='.$id.') a)');
```

en la salida me devuelve esto `[{"cuota":4}]`
pero lo que necesito es solamente un 4 por qué?

les explico: en mi blade si yo coloco esto: `{{$cuota[0]->cuota}}` me aparece reflejado en pantalla el número 4 sin ningún problema, pero si quiero hacer esto:

```
@if({{$cuota[0]->cuota}} >= 5)
```

me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '<' (View:
```

Comment: Cuando haces uso de la directiva `@if` no es necesario poner las llaves `{{ }}`

Comment: Gracias, sé que ya había probado pero de plano tenía algo mas que estaba equivocado, gracias @L.Flor siempre me salvas la vida.

Comment: Gracias, sé que ya había probado pero de plano tenía algo mas que estaba equivocado, gracias @L.Flor siempre me salvas la vida.